# Wrapping a C++ Member Function Pointer (Emscripten)

Tags: c++, emscripten

I would like to create a wrapper around a C++ member function, which does some additional tasks before calling the actual member function. I'm working with Emscripten and my example below is using the [`.function` function](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/9b2514760dbcbec049ad6c332a038e5c735be7fa/system/include/emscripten/bind.h#L1567).

Let's say I have a class called `SomeClass` (which I don't "own", i.e. it's coming from a third party library) with a single static member function:

```cpp
class SomeClass {
public:
  void test(int& number) {
    number++;
  }
};
```

Normally, I would create Emscripten bindings with Embind like this:

```cpp
class_<SomeClass>("SomeClass")
  .function("test", 
    &SomeClass::test
  )
;
```

However, I would like to use a wrapper around that method, like this (C++ - JS - Pseudo-Code)

```cpp
class_<SomeClass>("SomeClass")
  .function("test", 
    &((this) => {
      int i = 0;
      this->test(i);
    })
  )
;
```

Is that somehow possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this pointer and static function don't go along very well

Comment: Yeah, I see... I edited my post and exchanged the static function for a non-static method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Emscripten seems to be design with such a use-case in mind and offers a [specialization of the `RegisterClassMethod` struct for `std::function`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/9b2514760dbcbec049ad6c332a038e5c735be7fa/system/include/emscripten/bind.h#L1370).

Using the following code, I can achieve what I want to do.

```cpp
class_<SomeClass>("SomeClass")
  .function("test", std::function<void(SomeClass&)>([](SomeClass& s) {
    int i = 0;
    s.test(i);
  }))
;
```